# Android Activity reopens from background when FIrebase Database event triggers

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am registering my event listener inside the `onStart()` and then I am removing my listener inside `onStop()`. It seems like the listener is never removed, because when something changes in the database, the Activity reopens itself, even when the app was on the background.

Is anyone else experiencing this problem? I would appreciate any help or advice.

Comment: When you say, "the Activity reopens itself", do you mean the activity comes to the foreground?

Comment: We need to see code for this type of thing. Especially lifecycle methods.

Comment: @qbix Yes I meant it comes to the foreground.

Comment: @VlpplpRyguy it's as simple as having a ChildListener on an Activity that modifies a list when ever a child changed.

Comment: I've followed the Firebase issues on SO closely and not seen reports of this problem.  Post the applicable parts of your code or a [mcve].